# Google Analytics - Show logged in users and user status

Tags: google, google-analytics, cookie, users, real-time

I have control on the site and can set cookies or whatever necessary to mark the users, but not sure hot to set google analytics to allow me see breakdown of users by the login status and member status.

How can I set the realtime to show me logged in users, and if logged in user member type (free/premium)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't *think* that is possible via real time reports. Real time reporting offers a limited set of data and standard ga segments do not work with real time reporting.

To see what is offered by the real time reporting, more specific information can be found on the following page
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638637?hl=en&ref_topic=1638563

To track it with GA in the standard reports, create a custom dimension for Login Status and another for Member Type, then pass the dimensions/values with events or pageviews. Eg track site logins via onsubmit of the login form and pass the dimension value of logged-in with the event. Once logged in, fire another event to send the dimension of the Member Type or pass the dimension and it's value with their pageviews.

For information on how to configure custom dimensions in the GA interface:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en&ref_topic=2709827

and the related dev docs for the required code:
*Universal analytics.js custom dimensions*
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets
*Gtag.js custom dimensions*
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets